# Specify Data type In OO Haskell

Tags: haskell

In this Haskell code the constructor arguments(length and width) can be of any data type (like Int,Char etc.). Is there a way by which i can explicitly specify the data type of length and width? **How can i specify the return type of function getLength**?

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls, DeriveDataTypeable, TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fcontext-stack=100 #-}

module Rectangle where

import OOHaskell

$(label "getLength")
$(label "getWidth")
$(label "incr")
$(label "lengthenBy")
$(label "setLength")
$(label "setWidth")
$(label "show'")

rectangle length width self
 = do
     lengthRef <- newIORef length
     widthRef <- newIORef width
     return $
          getLength      .=. readIORef lengthRef
      .*. getWidth      .=. readIORef widthRef
      .*. setLength      .=. writeIORef lengthRef
      .*. setWidth      .=. writeIORef widthRef
      .*. lengthenBy    .=. (\dl ->
              do
             length <- self # getLength
             (self # setLength) (length + dl))
      .*. incr          .=. (self # lengthenBy) (1)
      .*. show'         .=. printLn ("Length : "<< self # getLength<<" Width : "<< self # getWidth)
      .*. emptyRecord
```

The main should work (which it is) if it is written like:

```
main = do
   c1 <- mfix $ rectangle 0 0
   c2 <- mfix $ rectangle 0 0
   c3 <- mfix $ rectangle 0 0
   c1# setWidth $ 3
   c2# setWidth $ 2
   c3# setWidth $ 2
   c1# incr
   c2# incr
   c1# incr
   c1# show'
   c3# show'
```

But main is working even if it is written this way which is undesirable( as width cannot be a character).

```
main = do
   c1 <- mfix $ rectangle 0 'a'
   c2 <- mfix $ rectangle 0 'b'
   c3 <- mfix $ rectangle 0 'c'
   c1# setWidth $ 'd'
   c2# setWidth $ 'e'
   c3# setWidth $ 'f'
   c1# incr
   c2# incr
   c1# incr
   c1# show'
   c3# show'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is all type-safe, the return type of `getLength` will match the contents of `lengthRef`, so you just need to add a type signature somewhere that constrains that type, and the type of `getLength` should be inferred correctly from that.

For example, you can specify the type when creating `lengthRef`:

```
lengthRef <- newIORef (length :: Int)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way by which i can explicitly specify the data type of length and width?

yes:

```
rectangle :: TypeOfLength -> TypeOfWidth -> TypeOfSelf -> ReturnTypeOfRectangle
rectangle length width self = ...
```

> How can i specify the return type of function getLength?

I never use OOHaskell so I'm not sure about this. Basically, you could declare types that a function expects (as arguments) and its return type. The syntax is like rectangle above, return type is always the right most one.

Reference: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Type_basics#Type_signatures_in_code

Comment: But then what will be the TypeOfSelf and ReturnTypeOfRectangle??

Comment: I guess that's related to OOHaskell, you should consult the documentation whether the self pointer has to be the last argument or what. In common object oriented language, it's usually the top level object or a plain pointer. I don't know their equivalent in OOHaskell

Answer (score 1):

You could always add type annotations to your constructor, for example when you create the `IORef`s, something like:

```
widthRef :: IORef Int <- newIORef width
```

Or the equivalent on the function argument `width` itself.